# Flutter Firebase FCM notification always a white/grey square rather than the custom app icon

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

Tried all the advice from Stackoverflow, but didn't make any difference:
Put this into the AndroidManifest

```
 <application
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    android:label="Honest"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <!-- Set custom default icon. This is used when no icon is set for incoming notification messages. -->
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification" />
    <!-- Set color used with incoming notification messages. This is used when no color is set for the incoming notification message.  -->
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
    <activity
```

Then tried putting the ic notification in different folders - no difference! And putting the png icon into drawables folder directly...
Played with vector and png - nothing works... still the same grey square...

The res folder looks as follows:

```
│   ├── launch_background.xml
│   └── orange_tick.xml

├── drawable-hdpi
│   ├── ic_stat_ic_notification.png
│   └── ic_stat_notification.png

├── drawable-mdpi
│   ├── ic_stat_ic_notification.png
│   └── ic_stat_notification.png

├── drawable-xhdpi
│   ├── ic_stat_ic_notification.png
│   └── ic_stat_notification.png

├── drawable-xxhdpi
│   ├── ic_stat_ic_notification.png
│   └── ic_stat_notification.png

├── drawable-xxxhdpi
│   ├── ic_stat_ic_notification.png
│   └── ic_stat_notification.png

├── mipmap-hdpi
│   └── ic_launcher.png
├── mipmap-mdpi
│   └── ic_launcher.png
├── mipmap-xhdpi
│   └── ic_launcher.png
├── mipmap-xxhdpi
│   └── ic_launcher.png
├── mipmap-xxxhdpi
│   └── ic_launcher.png
└── values
    ├── colors.xml
    ├── strings.xml
    └── styles.xml
```

Anyone spots what I'm doing wrong that it doesn't work would be super!!

Flutter doctor all clean, the android device is a Ulefone Power 2 with Android 7.0 if that makes any difference...

Comment: Did you figure this one out?

Comment: It's been a few changes I've been working on since last week on various other aspects, but I think the main ones were upgrading to Androidx and updating all the firebase packages to the latest versions. After this I've now started seeing the custom icon. Yay! So recommend you do the same and also re-build the gradle from scratch as well.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of this issue is that there's no custom default icon is set and no icon is set in the notification payload, as mentioned in this [guide](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging#custom-default-icon). If the icon has just recently been added, you can try running the app using restart to make sure that all components are included in your build. If that didn't work, you can also check this [thread on GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17941) relevant to this issue.

Comment: This is a guidance but not really an answer